# Example for caching the options for the .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

There are 3 major options interface in .net core, IOptions, IOptionsSnapshot and IOptionsMonitor. I would like to inject the IOptionsMonitor to my singleton service and read the updated value during the runtime. However, the config is collected from the webapi and it will take a long time to fetch. so I want to cache it. I found something called IOptionsMoniorCache. but I cannot find any example about how to use it. Is there any example to illustrate how could we use this cache?